# Retrieve Subtitle/Caption information from REST API for Video 365 Videos in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, office-365-video-portal

I'm looking to use the REST API to pull additional metadata like subtitle or caption track info. I have videos with the `.VTT` tracks loaded in the Video 365 module and can access those subtitles when embedding the video manually. However, I'm wanting to use the REST API to call a channel of video to display dynamically.  Can the subtitle files be accessed and told to play with a certain dialect dynamically?

An example would be something like:

`GET {VideoPortalURL}/_api/videoservice/Channels('{channelId}')/search/query('{videoId}')?$Select={TextTrack}`

Has anyone done this or something similar?

Comment: Where do you want to call the REST API from? SharePoint or somewhere else?

Comment: I want to call the REST API from a SharePoint Online site.

Comment: @KevinStone  I got the idea after recently coming across a new(er) posting by Mark Rackley regarding pulling Video 365 content into a SharePoint Online site [http://www.markrackley.net/2016/06/13/integrate-your-office-365-video-portal-with-sharepoint-online/].  He's integrated Masonry.js and Flip.js with the REST API to make something very slick.  However, I'm looking to added subtitles for work that require multiple language subtitling.

Comment: hmm you could potentially use the SharePoint List REST API. The video binaries are technically stored in SharePoint document libraries. I've read that apparently, each channel has its own site collection. In that site collection is a library which contains the files. You could use the List REST API endpoints to get info on List items. I've never worked with video before, so this is just a theory. For multilingual, you could potentially use the TitleResource property for the corresponding list items?